# What does mean to similar folders in Spring Boot folders structure?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've faced a need to meet the Spring Boot (for making RestFul API) and I'm following official documentation here https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/.

I've cloned a specified repo https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service.git and run the project via executing ./gradlew bootRun inside a /complete folder.

Everything is ok, but I didn't catch that project folders structure mean...

Now it looks as below:

[image]

What are reasons to have 2 similar folders and what they are for?

Comment: The `complete` directory contains the completed tutorial.

Comment: you didn't follow (the tutorial) carefully!?;) they (spring.io) could have solved it via branches/tags, but that is their "default" repository structure (for all/many [gs-guides](https://github.com/spring-guides))

Comment: the reason (i think) is, that we should comprehend/diff;)/look at the changes from initial to complete.. :-)

Comment: This not a "standard" layout.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need both folders. This repository contains a tutorial/guide, and as the name states, the `complete` folder is the solution.
If you follow the guide in the README file, start with the code in the `initial` folder.